# Selenium Python Issue -- Can't reach li items in dynamic menus

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im trying to loop through each item under the url:
https://www.zara.com/es/en/man-jeans-l659.html?v1=2351397
Click add to cart (small + button on each item) then get the li's in the window that pop's up:

[image: each size is li item]

My code until now:

```
import time
options = Options()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.zara.com/es/en/man-jeans-l659.htmlv1=2351397")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button[class = "zds-button geolocation-modal__button zds-button--primary"]'))).click()
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class = "product-add-to-cart__button"]')
for button in buttons:
 button.click()  
 print(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.size-selector-list__wrapper size-selector-list__wrapper--grid size-selector-list__wrapper--open > ul.size-selector-list > li.size-selector-list__item"))
 time.sleep(1)
```

Tried many ways but couldn't get the li items propertly.

Comment: _couldn't get the li items propertly_ This doesn't tell us what the actual problem is.  Please show us the actual results from the code, and explain exactly how those results weren't what you expected.

Comment: The actual problem is that the li items can't be found when I search them by class, I'm getting empty results

Comment: Maybe you're using a wrong css selector?  How did you get the exact value for the css selector that you are using?

Comment: You said the li's appear in a pop-up window.  I don't know for sure, but I think you have to do something special to tell the driver to search the pop-up window instead of the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should wait for the elements before interacting with them
2. Your locator to /li elements doesn't find any elements. You can check it via dev tools (F12 in chrome > elements tab > Ctrl+F)

The following part of the code works ok for me:

```
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    buttons = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.product-add-to-cart__button')))
    for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
        actions.move_to_element(button).click().perform()

        sizes = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    'div.size-selector-list__wrapper--open > ul.size-selector-list > li div.product-size-info__main-label'
                )
            )
        )

        print(f"Product {i} sizes: {[x.get_attribute('innerHTML') for x in sizes]}")
```

Output:

```
Product 0 sizes: ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 1 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44']
Product 2 sizes: ['38', '40', '42', '44']
Product 3 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44']
Product 4 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 5 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 6 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 7 sizes: ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 8 sizes: ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 9 sizes: ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 10 sizes: ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 11 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 12 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 13 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 14 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 15 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 16 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 17 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 18 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46']
Product 19 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
Product 20 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
Product 21 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
Product 22 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
Product 23 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
Product 24 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
Product 25 sizes: ['36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']
```